# python syntax for functions with multiple return values: using fsolve

Tags: python, numpy, syntax, scipy

I am new to python and trying to convert some matlab code as an exercise. One of the tasks involves finding the root, or minimum absolute value if no root exists, of a function. I can do that just fine, but I want to add some error checking to see that scipy.optimize.fsolve actually finds a solution. In particular, fsolve returns a parameter ier which is just a success flag and I want to read it.

My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve, minimize

mu = -8
sigma = 4
mun = -2
ARL0 = 2000
hmin = 0.5
hmax = 100

f = lambda h: (np.exp(-2*mun*(h/sigma+1.166))-1+2*mun*(h/sigma+1.166))/(2*mun**2)-ARL0

if f(hmin)*f(hmax) < 0:
    opth, ier = fsolve(f,hmax)
    print ier
    print opth[0]
else:
    f = lambda h: np.abs((np.exp(-2*mun*(h/sigma+1.166))-1+2*mun*(h/sigma+1.166))/(2*mun**2)-ARL0)
    opth = minimize(f,hmax,bounds=((hmin,hmax),))
    print opth.success
    print opth.x[0]
```

The "else" bit works fine, it prints the solution and a true/false if it found one. The first if block doesn't: I get the following error when it runs:

```
line 14, in <module>
opth, ier = fsolve(f,hmax)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I'm guessing it's just a synatx error but I haven't been able to find an example using fsolve to do this. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It looks like you may need to set `full_output=1` going into `fsolve()` [Fsolve() Docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html)

Comment: I would also add that getting hold of an IDE (I use PyCharm) helps immensely when using external libraries like scipy and numpy. Because of the nature of Python packages, you can usually just jump straight to the function definition from a context menu or with a hotkey.

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick. I will look into an IDE as well.

Comment: If you happen to be a student or otherwise associated with an education institution, PyCharm Professional is free: https://www.jetbrains.com/student/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the argument `full_output=True` and there are actually 4 return values, looking at [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html), so you need to unpack all of them.

Here's the source for `fsolve` in my version of SciPy (0.14.0), you can see the two options for return values:

```
def fsolve(func, x0, args=(), fprime=None, full_output=0,
       col_deriv=0, xtol=1.49012e-8, maxfev=0, band=None,
       epsfcn=None, factor=100, diag=None):

    options = {'col_deriv': col_deriv,
               'xtol': xtol,
               'maxfev': maxfev,
               'band': band,
               'eps': epsfcn,
               'factor': factor,
               'diag': diag,
               'full_output': full_output}

    res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)
    if full_output:
        x = res['x']
        info = dict((k, res.get(k))
                    for k in ('nfev', 'njev', 'fjac', 'r', 'qtf') if k in res)
        info['fvec'] = res['fun']
        return x, info, res['status'], res['message']
    else:
        return res['x']
```